# Invalid identifier: ORA ORA-00904; Hibernate ignoring Intellij-IDEA generated @Column (name="") annotation on getter

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-jpa

I have a Spring boot application (2.1.5) using Hibernate (5.1), as my JPA provider, accessing an Oracle 11.2.0.4 DB, with Hibernate Dialect Oracle10gDialect

I have created a repo like this

```
@Repository
public interface VehStoRepository extends CrudRepository<VehStoEntity, Long>
{
}
```

and my Entity is as follows

```
@Entity @Table(name = "VEH_STO", schema = "MySchema") 
public class  VehStoEntity
{
  @Id
  private long eventNo;
  private Long stoType;

  Basic @Column(name = "STO_TYPE", nullable = true, precision = 0) 
  public Long getStoType()
  {
    return stoType;
  }

  public void setStoType(Long stoType)
  {
    this.stoType = stoType;
  }
... 
}
```

With many other fields etc, that I have excluded for brevity. I had the persistence mapping generated by Intellj Idea.

Now, when calling 
`vehStoRepository.findAll();`
I get the following error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "VEHSTOENT0_"."STOTYPE": invalid identifier

My SQL statement as the logs show it is:

> Hibernate: select vehstoent0_.stoType as stoType25_0_ from MYSCHEMA.VEH_STO vehstoent0_

My question is: does hibernate actually add ent0 to the entity name or is this just weird logging, or is this the cause of the error? Is this because I have not generated an ORM mapping schema for all tables, just for the one I needed? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11524574/9596875):

My sql table was a view, so I assume that's why Intellij didn't create an `@Id` annotation.
So i created the @Id manually over the field, but Intellij had the  `@Column (name="")`

annotation on the getter, which Hibernate then ignored.

I have solved the problem by moving all annotations to the fields instead.